# How to store numpy.ndarray on DynamoDB?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, amazon-dynamodb, numpy-ndarray

I have this `numpy.ndarray` generated by [@ageitgey's](https://github.com/ageitgey) [facial_recognition Python library](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) when I call the `face_encodings` function. I need to save this data to Amazon's DynamoDB; but I'm not sure how.

The `numpy.ndarray` that I get when I run the `face_encodings` function, is a representation of a person's face, from a given image. I can use this data to compare to another image, and check if the person (represented as an encoding) is present or not in that image.

I thought that I could save the `numpy.ndarray` as a binary (using [numpy.ndarray.tobytes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html), but I'm not sure how to transform that binary (when I retrieve the data back from DynamoDB) back to `numpy.ndarray`.

My code to compare should be something like this:

```
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_picture)[0]
# database_encoding_array should come from DynamoDB
results = face_recognition.compare_faces(database_encoding_array, unknown_encoding, tolerance=0.595)
# results is an array of booleans
```

In summary, I don't know what's the best way to save a `numpy.ndarray` to DynamoDB, and how to query it at a later time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try converting `results` to a string of bytes using `ndarray.tostring`. This should be straightforward to work with for Dynamo.

```
arr = np.array([1, 2])

encoded = arr.tostring()
encoded
# b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

You can then restore the array using `np.frombuffer`.

```
np.array_equal(arr, np.frombuffer(encoded, dtype=int))
# True
```

Comment: It worked! In my case, since it's an array of **floats**, I should just call `np.frombuffer` without the `dtype` parameter, since the default type is **float**

Comment: @cesarvargas Great that you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Is there a way to handle with with AWS DataWrangler, I am reading the DataFrame with wrangler, this frame does have a ndarray column that's causing issue while putting DF to dyanamoDB.